# MS Access retrieve data between two dates using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, ms-access-2007

I want to retrieve data between two dates from MS Access using JDBC.

I have tried

```
String query= "SELECT lastlogin FROM loginHistory " +
            "WHERE lastlogin BETWEEN #01/07/2013# AND #03/07/2013#"+
            "ORDER BY lastLogin DESC";
```

I am not getting the desired results.
Whats the problem. please help me out !

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got the solution by transforming the date format from `01/07/2013` to `2013/07/01`

```
String query= "SELECT lastlogin FROM loginHistory " +
            "WHERE lastlogin BETWEEN #2013/07/01# AND #2013/07/03#"+
            "ORDER BY lastLogin DESC";
```

Thank You all for supporting me..

Answer (score 0):

`Query` missed the `"` in the end  and you added in the middle.

Try

```
String query= "SELECT lastlogin FROM loginHistory " +
            "WHERE lastlogin BETWEEN #01/07/2013# AND #03/07/2013# "+
            "ORDER BY lastLogin DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax is correct, but you have an extra quotation mark in the middle of your code, directly after the first date in the BETWEEN clause.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not getting the desired results.

I believe then your code compiles but you are not getting the resultset what you expect. Although your code posted over here misses a quotation mark. I believe that it is a typo , or else the code wouldn't have compiled itself.

Check if the date string in the query is in correct format . Execute the query as a `PreparedStatement` :

```
String query= "SELECT lastlogin FROM loginHistory " +
        "WHERE lastlogin BETWEEN ? AND ?"+
        "ORDER BY lastLogin DESC";
```

And set the date strings after formatting it properly using `Date` format. Also check what is the datatype for your column , is it `VARCHAR/String` or `DATE` etc. You can even use the `format()` in the sql query itself :

```
Select lastlogin From loginHistory where format(lastlogin,"dd/mm/yyyy")
BETWEEN  format(#01/07/2013#,"dd/mm/yyyy") AND 
format(#03/07/2013#,"dd/mm/yyyy") ORDER BY lastLogin DESC;
```

Comment: I have already formatted the date to format "dd/MM/yyyy".. Now for PreparedStatement i have used setString(1.from) & setString(2,to)

Comment: and its giving Exception as : [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'lastlogin BETWEEN Pa_RaM000 AND Pa_RaM001ORDER BY lastLogin DESC'.

Comment: for your 2nd query its giving SQLException : Too few parameters. Expected 1.

Comment: Execute the 2nd query and check !

Comment: Executed the second query and gives SQLException : Too few parameters. Expected 1.